# Report on every child and grandchild account's Opportunity in the HQ layout, that includes HQ Opportunities.

Tags: reporting, account

I'm trying to report on the Opportunity Data within our organisation in the HQ account. I've managed to report on the data from the child account using the Parent ID as the filter. Unfortunately it doesn't let me filter by both Parent Id and Ultimate Parent ID.

[image]

When I set the Parent Id as the filter the report displays as such:

[image]

Is there a way to include all of the child, grandchild records and the records from the actual account?

Comment: I guess you could try use custom reports feature, but I can't check right now

Answer (score 1):

Given that your ERD looks like this:

[image: ERD]

Then I would tell you to create a [Custom Report Type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_defining_report_types.htm&type=0) on the children which includes the fathers and grandfathers.

Once you have the report type, create the report as a *Summary* type and group first by the grandfather and then by the father.

[image]

Finally, if you want to filter out certain parents, just use the actual filters.